# Como fazer uma tela em asp.net MVC, que relaciona os ID's de uma mesma tabela

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Bom tenho pouca experiencia em programação então preciso de ajuda quanto a isso.

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada **Pessoa**, e uma tabela pra criar o relacionamento entre ela mesmo que se chama **PessoaParceiro**, relacionamento 1 para vários.  ou seja, o **IdPessoa** da Tbl **PessoaParceiro** é o **idPessoa = x** da tbl **Pessoa** e o **IdParceiro** da tbl **PessoaParceiro** tambem é um **IdPessoa = Y**.

eu tenho uma view index da controler Pessoa onde lista pra mim todas as pessoas cadastradas existente na tabela Pessoa, na minha ideia eu criaria um botao na view index "relacionar pessoa" que redirecionaria para uma outra tela carregando o id da pessoa em contexto na URL (carregar o id eu consigo).. mas nao tenho a minima ideia de como criar essa view "relacionar pessoa" onde eu gostaria de poder buscar a pessoa por nome, e clicar nela ja alimentando a tabela PessoaParceiro

Alguem tem um codigo de exemplo?? 
Lembrando estou usando EntityFramework 6

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo, sugiro você tentar especificar um pouco mais o que precisa saber. Consegui entender que precisa criar um relacionamento da tabela Pessoa em 2 campos chave na tabela PessoaPerceiro. Ótimo. Mas você precisa de exemplo de quê? Tente especificar um pouco mais

Comment: Bom ta dificil ate pra explica, rsrs, mas vamos la, eu tenho uma view index da controler  Pessoa onde lista pra mim todas as pessoas cadastradas existente na tabela Pessoa, na minha ideia eu criaria um botao na view index "relacionar pessoa"  que redirecionaria para uma outra tela carregando o id da pessoa em contexto na URL (carregar o id eu consigo).. mas nao tenho a minima ideia de como criar essa view "relacionar pessoa" onde eu gostaria de poder buscar a pessoa por nome, e clicar nela ja alimentando a tabela PessoaParceiro

Comment: Para a ViewRelacionarPessoa pode-se criar da mesma maneira que na Index, onde lista todas as pessoas. Nesse caso, seleciona a pessoa a ser relacionada (pois você ja tem a primeira pessoa, que foi passada como parâmetro) e cria um botão salvar.

Comment: Você pode evitar trabalho, selecionando as duas pessoas na mesma tela. Pegando a ID das duas pessoas ao mesmo tempo, evitando assim mais trabalho.